# How to trigger AWS Cloudwatch event only via put_events

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

My end goal is to start an ECS (fargate) task/Lambda based on API call (manually).
When creating the CloudWatch Rule I have to select a service to listen events on. I'm not sure what service I should use for my purpose.
What is the best thing to do? Should I create a CloudWatch alarm that I manually trigger?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you want to trigger a lambda function/ECS task based on an API call.This cloudwatch event rule service will depend on the type of API call you are running.

For example if there is a S3 Put event ,then you will select the S3 as the service and then the specific S3 operation you are running

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.s3"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "PutObject"
    ]
  }
}
```

If this a non-aws API call then you can use cloudwatch logs to trigger the Cloudwatch event rule.

Comment: Thanks, I am more looking for non-aws API calls, not related to another aws service. How do you use cloudwatch log to trigger the rule?